# Wordpress sub menus not triggering properly

Tags: jquery, css

I have a basic vertical menu that consist of 6 buttons.

When someone clicks a button that is not a sub menu, it goes to that page. Great!

If the clicked button has a sub-menu, the sub-menu slides down and nothing more happens. When someone clicks a link in the sub-menu, it goes to that link.

The issue is that when you click a link in a sub-menu, it just slides up and does nothing. Am losing my mind.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children">
        <a>Button 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-240"><a href="">Button 1.1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-238"><a href="">Button 1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-244" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-244"><a>Button 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-236"><a href="">Button 2.1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-235"><a href="">Button 2.2</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-234"><a href="">Button 2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-484" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item"><a href="">Button 3</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-231"><a href="">Button 4</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-302" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-302"><a href="">Button 5</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-230" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-230"><a href="">Button 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".menu-item-has-children").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('> .sub-menu').addClass('sub-menu-down').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

I am also looking to make it so that if the button 2 menu is open and someone clicks button 1, the button 2 menu slides shut as or before the button 1 menu slides open. (That is jsut where I am heading if anyone has any ideas).

Mega props and thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I stripped out some of the classes from the wordpress so it was not so long.

Comment: try `.find('.sub-menu')` instead of  `.find('> .sub-menu')`

Comment: That looks good so far. Still trying to fix the sub-menu sliding up when a link in the sub-menu is clicked. Thanks again for the insight.

Comment: a little thought.. since you know it's gonna be a direct child.. `.children('.sub-menu')` would be faster than `.find('.sub-menu')`

Comment: Hey. Good question. I tried that but the issue is that if that .sub-menu also had a sub-menu (third level), they would both slide open when clicking to 1st to second level. At least that is what I have found. Having said that, I am actually wanting to allow unlimited (or at least third level) menu access. The answer below that solved the issue I found allows for two level. By using the 'not' command, as soon as I clicked into the third level, it would shut the second which would also shut the third.

Comment: I have created something on codepen if you wanted to take a look http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVyBEj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use*

```
$(".menu-item-has-children").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Hide other menus
    //Find .sub-menu belonging to other menu-item-has-children
    //thus used .not() and 
    $(".menu-item-has-children").not(this).find('> .sub-menu').slideUp()

    //Slide this
    $(this).find('> .sub-menu').addClass('sub-menu-down').slideToggle();
});
```

Reference [`$.fn.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

Comment: That looks good. It appears to make the menus slide properly. The only issue is that if you click Button 1.2, that sub-menu slides up and does not go to the web address attached to button 1.2. I almost feel like it is something so small but I am missing it. A big thank you by the way for your very quick response.

Comment: @MurrayChapman,  remove `event.preventDefault();` it prevents default action, Since that was part of your answer I left it that way

Comment: Okay. That got it to work. Wow. Something so small. I had that in there originally as the top level button 1 and button 2 have empty a tags. Wordpress put it that way and sadly Safari bugs out on empty a tags returning popups or errors. Void of that, you have fixed the issue so I am really appreciative. Wished there was a buy a beer button around here somewhere :) Again, many thanks.

Comment: Hi Satpal. A quick question and I don't want to take you away from what you are doing for more that a minute. The code above fixed the issue perfectly for a two level. What if I wanted a three (or four?)

Comment: Ikeep forgetting a soon as you hit enter, it submits. LOL. I sometimes get asked if I can do something that supports three levels or maybe more. By using the 'not' syntax, that is perfect for two level but as soon as I click into the third level, it slides the second level as it is not the active sub-menu. I have created a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVyBEj just in case you wanted to take a look but totally cool if no and appreciating the help you gave me to solve the previous issue.